# Permission denied even when run with sudo

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, backup

I have a large 3TB NTFS formatted hard drive in my PC which I use for storage.  I am trying to back it up onto an external drive.  Every 6 months when I upgrade ubuntu I copy my home directory into the Backup folder this drive.  I now am trying to backup that onto an external drive.  This issue I am having is that I keep getting permission denied errors.  I am using the archive-manager to copy the contents of my old home directories into an .tar.gz format.  The error says I did not have permission to access something in my wine directory.  I tried running sudo chown -R  Backups on the 3TB drive but this did not fix the issue.  Next I ran both nautilus and the archive manager with sudo permissions and I still get the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like in my wine folders it was linking to my Z: drive which is the root directory.  Once I deleted all the wine folders it works.